# Passing japanese parameters in JSONP requests

Tags: jsonp

Iam having a spring MVC application hosted in a tomcat server.
I tried to develop a widget which could be embedded in any client application for searching 
in the external spring MVC application.
I used JSONP in the client application for communicating with the external application.
but iam not able to pass japanese characters as request parameters as it is into the spring mvc application.
Here is the client side code I used.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url : "http://abc.com:8080/myTestapp/search?callback=mycallback",                
data: ({name : $('#form-refineSearchQuery').val(),iDisplayStart : 0,iDisplayLength: 100}),
dataType: "jsonp",
beforeSend: function(x) {
    if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
        x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
}
},

jsonp : false,                                              

});
```

I have an input text box with id form-refineSearchQuery where I gave a japanese character.
But the request parameter is getting encoded into some other format and is reaching the server as some encoded data eg :æ??å¸?å­?

This is the parameter i gave in the input text box-  有希子
Any help?since this issue is causing the search in the spring application to fail

Comment: is it application/j-son? or should it be application/json

Comment: Both are working(json,j-son)

Comment: Also even when I am giving the same request URL in the adress bar of my  browser, same thing is happening.

Comment: on analysys I note that the request parameter is wrongly decoded in ISO-8859-1 format by the servlet.So I added the attribute URIEncoding="UTF-8" in componet tag of server.xml of the tomcat application, but of no goodness.

Comment: is there any other way where we can specify the servlet to decode request parameters in character set UTF-8 format?

Comment: try something like this : final String param = URLDecoder
        .decode(new String(request.getParameter("param").getBytes(
                "iso-8859-1")), "UTF-8");

Comment: It's not decoding back to UTF-8 aven after this

Comment: have you checked in firebug , what exactly is being sent out

Comment: Iam using chrome and the request url I sent was http://myIPadress:8080/myapp/search?callback=mycallback&name=%E6%9C%89%E5%B8%8C%E5%AD%90&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=100&_=1367224513606.Here the name parameter value is encoded correctly in UTF- format %E6%9C%89%E5%B8%8C%E5%AD%90 by the borwser (the original value being 有希子).This should be decoded by the server in UTF-8 format which is not the case right now

Answer (score 0):

Hey there user2330825!

The problem comes from how JSONP is implemented--it creates a script tag within the DOM, and submits from there as a GET request, and browsers will typically ignore any encoding specification from that, and rely instead on the response encoding. Try adding a charset attribute to your Content-type header on the response (i.e., in the request handling on the server side, `set_header("Content-type", "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8"`), and see if that works for you.